# How to run jasmine-node in WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm, jasmine-node

I've installed nodejs and jasmine-node and it runs in command line.

Configuration of WebStorm Runner:

1. Node parameters: `jasmine-node --config endpoint ServerAddress:8083`
2. Working directory: `G:\NPWorkDir\frisby`
3. JavaScript file: `src\protocol\find_spec.js`

#### WebStorm Terminal:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm\bin\runnerw.exe" "G:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node.exe" jasmine-node --config endpoint ServerAddress:8083 
G:\NPWorkDir\frisby\src\
protocol\find_spec.js

module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'G:\NPWorkDir\tester-frisbys\jasmine-node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to specify `node_modules\jasmine-node\bin\jasmine-node` as a **JavaScript file**, passing `--config` option and you .js file as **Application parameters**, like;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Full configuration to run jsmine-node:**

1. Install jasmine node with -save parameter:

   npm install jasmine-node -save
2. Configuration WebStorm runner with this parameters:

   - javaScript file -home directiory-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\jasmine-node\lib\jasmine-node\cli.js
   - Application parameters: //path to your test files

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses linux instead of windows pathnames!

I would recommend jasmine instead of jasmine-node, it seems to be more actual. Create the configuration with

```
./node_modules/.bin/jasmine init
```

edit `jasmine.json` if necessary.

I would create a npm script in `package.json` as:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "node_modules/.bin/jasmine",
  ...
},
```

and define it in Webstorm as npm script; *command:* **run**, *script:* **test**